# Regarding the license's condition(MIT, BSD-3...), how to satisfy the condition "License and copyright notice"?

Tags: mit, license, bsd

For example, in the laravel project, when I run the command composer i, all the packages which were specified in composer.json will be installed in the vendor folder.

As long as each of them already includes the license file in the source code, I don't need to worry about the "License and copyright notice" condition anymore because all of them already include the license file in the licensed material(which is the source code of that package) after installing via composer, right? If not, please show me how to do that.

Then I can add my own license file for my project in the main source code and use it for whatever I want (private use, open source, commercial use...).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for source-code distributions.

If you distribute your software in a binary format, then you should take steps to ensure the copyright and licensing information of the third-party code that is present in your binary is also available to the recipients of your binary.

If your binary has a GUI, then you could arrange for a screen where all the copyright and licensing information can be seen by the user. Or you can distribute some documentation together with your binary that has the information.